# Calculate value of $ f'(0)$ of function $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {\sin(nx)}{n^3}, f: {\bf R}\to{\bf R}.$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I tried to solve it in the following way:

$$f'(x) = \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(nx)}{n^3}\right)'=
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \frac{\sin(nx)}{n^3}\right)'=
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(n x \cos(n x)-3 \sin(n x))}{n^4}$$

$$f'(0) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{0}{n^4} =0$$

Is it a good answer?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that you are not differentiating with respect to $x$, but with respect to $n$. That's not what I think the problem is going after.

Comment: No, $(\frac{\sin nx}{n^3})'=\frac{\cos nx}{n^2}$

Comment: Ok, so answer should be $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}= \frac{\pi^2}{6}$?

Comment: @JosephConrad You got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\sin{(nx)}}{n^3}\right)=\frac{n\cos{(nx)}}{n^3}=\frac{\cos{(nx)}}{n^2}
$$
Hence, $$f'(0) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$$
What does this series converge to?

Answer (score 3):

First you should check if it's possible to differentiate series term by term, but in this case it's posible, because $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin nx}{n^3}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{\sin nx}{n^3})'$ converges for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$ (because $|\sin nx| \leq 1$, next use Weierstrass M-test), so:

$f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{\sin nx}{n^3})'=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{ \cos nx}{n^2}$

For $x=0$ we have:

$f'(0)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$

Answer (score 2):

I asume ' denotes an derivative with respect to $x$ $$\left( \frac{\sin(nx)}{n^3}\right)'=
n\frac{\cos(nx)}{n^3}= \frac{\cos(nx)}{n^2}$$
however your ansatz is correct. the reason why this is allowed is that the series converges absolutly.
$$f'(0) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(0)}{n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}=
\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$ 
you may search for "zeta(2)" if you want to know what happens in that last step.

Comment: This should be $\pi^2/6$ I believe

Comment: thanks, I simply forgot the square here